# Foreign collection field not present in db

Tags: java, h2, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have two simple class like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "movements")
public class Movement {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField
    double amount;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    Category category;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    Collection<Tag> tags;

    //Other stuff
}
```

And the second:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "tag")
public class Tag {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    Movement movement;

    @DatabaseField
    String name;

    //Other stuff
}
```

What I expect by the following two commands:

```
TableUtils.createTable(dbConnection, Tag.class);
TableUtils.createTable(dbConnection, Movement.class);
```

is the creation of two table inside the db with right references once to the other. Instean seems that the ForeignCollection inside the 'Movement' class was ignored. This is may debug infos:

```
[INFO] TableUtils creating table 'tag'
[INFO] TableUtils executed create table statement changed 0 rows: CREATE TABLE `tag` (`id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT , `movement_id` INTEGER , `name` VARCHAR(255) , PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) 
[INFO] TableUtils creating table 'movements'
[INFO] TableUtils executed create table statement changed 0 rows: CREATE TABLE `movements` (`id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT , `amount` DOUBLE PRECISION , `category_id` INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I can't see my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instean seems that the ForeignCollection inside the 'Movement' class was ignored.

Yeah it is a bit confusing but there is no mistake.  There is nothing in the `movements` table that refers to `tags` in the database.

The way foreign-collections work in ORMLite (like hibernate and other ORMs) is that a `tag` has a reference to the associated `movement_id`, but not the other way around.  A `movement` can't have some sort of list of `tag` ids by definition.  That's why ORMLite uses another query to fill out the `tags` collection.  It returns your `movement` and then it looks up the `id` from the `movement` to find the tags that have the same in the `movement_id` field.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My error is misunderstanding in what ORMLite work.